# How to add a custom indicator line to stacked bar chart in SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, builder, reportbuilder3.0

I have a stacked bar chart showing the sum of hours worked on each bar stacked by task types. I am looking to add an indicator bar that represents a "baseline number of hours worked" (shown as the green vertical line in the mock screenshot). I can get the value of this number from data-set but can't figure out how to add this line to the chart.

I have tried various settings of gauges and indicators but haven't been able to figure out a solution. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Mock screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using "minor tick marks" along horizontal axis.

In properties of horizontal axis -> "Minor Tick Marks", add the expression containing the value of "base line hours" in custom interval and format the position as "Inside". I did have to play with the "Length" property to make sure the line does not go higher than the chart itself.

Please note that I am using "Major Tick Marks" for small outside marks with the labels along horizontal axis so "minor tick marks" option was set to "Hide" before this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6JUh.png)

Here is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNtYB.jpg)

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a stripline. The down side is that they appear behind the bars so you might have to make you bars slightly narrower so you can see the line thru the gaps.

I built a simple example using the the following query for my dataset

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(g varchar(10), n varchar(10), x int)

    INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('X', 'A', 50),
    ('X', 'B', 75),
    ('Y', 'C', 100),
    ('X', 'D', 50),
    ('Y', 'E', 25)

    SELECT *, AVG(X) OVER() AS avg FROM @t
```

I then added a stacked bar chart as below

[image]

Next you need to make sure the properties windows is visible and click the horizontal axis. In the properties windows you will see the `StripLines` property as below.

[image]

Add a new strip line and set the properties as below, the expression is just my `avg` field from the dataset (I added a title for the strip line too). You can see the properties I edited in bold.

[image]

Finally when we run the report we get this.

[image]

It's not perfect but hopefully it solves you problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found another solution which works better using "minor tick mark" along the horizontal axis. I'll add details as answer shortly.