# Showing the current time on the graph

Tags: reporting-services

I have a line report on the SSRS and the last horizontal axis value is showing the time after the current time. So I would like to add a line to the graph to show to the current time before the last horizontal axis value.
My data structure like as below:
[image]
The output which I am expecting is:

[image]

I tried to add the current datetime value into the result set but it did not work.

Comment: Take a look at this answer. It does not use time values but the principle is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805711/how-to-add-a-custom-indicator-line-to-stacked-bar-chart-in-sql-server-report-bui/51808900#51808900

Comment: It doesn't work for DateTime data types, but I found another solution by referencing the link. Thanks @AlanSchofield